# sorting a queue using same queue in java

Tags: java, sorting, queue

hiii I'am trying to sort a queue using the same queue i think it should work but it doesn't ... it lost some elements ... any ideas?? here is the code

```
public void sort()
{
    for(int i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        Vertex tmp1=dequeue();
        Vertex tmp2=dequeue();
        Vertex max=tmp1;
        for(int j=1; j<size; j++)
        {
            if(tmp1.weight <= tmp2.weight)
            {
                enqueue(tmp1);
                tmp1=dequeue();
                max=tmp2;
            } else {
                max=tmp1;
                enqueue(tmp2);
                tmp2=dequeue();}
            }
            enqueue(max);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Also provide input and output

Comment: Either use `int i=0; i<size` or `int i=1; i<=size`, same with `for( int j`. What is `enqueue()` and `dequeue()` though ?

Answer (score 0):

> it lost some elements ... any ideas?

The reason you are losing elements is that you're calling `dequeue()` more times than you call `enqueue()`:

```
Vertex tmp1=dequeue();
Vertex tmp2=dequeue();
...
enqueue(max);
```

In the above, you have two `dequeue()` calls against one `enqueue()` calls (I am not including the calls from the inner loop since they are perfectly balanced).